# Combining aggregated columns into single table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate

I have two tables. One table shows me inbound inventory by month and the other shows me outbound inventory by month. Essentially I would like to show both inbound and outbound inventory by month on a single table.

1.

```
select 
warehouses.id,
count(pallets.id),
to_char(pallets.in_date, 'FMMonth-YY') as in_month

from pallets

inner join reservations
on pallets.reservation_id = reservations.id

inner join warehouses
on reservations.warehouse_id = warehouses.id

where pallets.in_date is not null

group by 
warehouses.id,
date_part('month', pallets.in_date),
date_part('year', pallets.in_date),
to_char(pallets.in_date, 'FMMonth-YY')

order by 
date_part('year', pallets.in_date),
date_part('month', pallets.in_date)
```

and 2.

```
select 
warehouses.id as id,
count(pallets.id),
to_char(pallets.out_date, 'FMMonth-YY') as out_month

from pallets

inner join reservations
on pallets.reservation_id = reservations.id

inner join warehouses
on reservations.warehouse_id = warehouses.id

where pallets.in_date is not null and pallets.out_date is not null

group by 
date_part('month', pallets.out_date),
date_part('year', pallets.out_date),
to_char(pallets.out_date, 'FMMonth-YY'),
warehouses.id

order by 
date_part('year', pallets.out_date),
date_part('month', pallets.out_date)
```

I tried to join the second table with a sub query but the returned values were all sorts of jacked up.

```
select 
warehouses.id,
count(pallets.id),
count(out.out),
to_char(pallets.in_date, 'FMMonth-YY') as in_month

from pallets

inner join reservations
on pallets.reservation_id = reservations.id

inner join warehouses
on reservations.warehouse_id = warehouses.id

full join (select 
warehouses.id as id,
count(pallets.id) as out,
to_char(pallets.out_date, 'FMMonth-YY') as out_month

from pallets

inner join reservations
on pallets.reservation_id = reservations.id

inner join warehouses
on reservations.warehouse_id = warehouses.id

where pallets.in_date is not null and pallets.out_date is not null

group by 
date_part('month', pallets.out_date),
date_part('year', pallets.out_date),
to_char(pallets.out_date, 'FMMonth-YY'),
warehouses.id

order by 
date_part('year', pallets.out_date),
date_part('month', pallets.out_date)) as out
on out.id=warehouses.id

where pallets.in_date is not null

group by 
warehouses.id,
date_part('month', pallets.in_date),
date_part('year', pallets.in_date),
to_char(pallets.in_date, 'FMMonth-YY')

order by 
date_part('year', pallets.in_date),
date_part('month', pallets.in_date)
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: no it's not very clear. If you post your tables, a few sample lines and an expected output it might become clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use the existing queries (with some minor modifications) as inline views.  And use a FULL OUTER JOIN operation to combine them.

No indication is given whether warehouse_id could be NULL or not, so in place of the equality comparison, the example below uses a "null-safe" comparison so NULL values of warehouse_id will get "matched" by the join operation.

And rather than use the DATE_PART and DATE_FORMAT, just use a DATE_TRUNC function in the inline views. That makes it easier to do the join, and the value from that can be used for ordering the result (if that's important) and for returning the month as a formatted string.  If this is going to be stored as a table, I would store the date value, rather than the formatted string.

I also prefer to use short table aliases to qualify the column references.

```
          select coalesce(i.warehouse_id,o.warehouse_id)                 as warehouse_id
               , coalesce(i.in_month,o.out_month)                        as month_
               , to_char(coalesce(i.in_month,o.out_month), 'FMMonth-YY') as month_yy
               , coalesce(i.cnt,0)                                       as in_count
               , coalesce(o.cnt,0)                                       as out_count
            from ( select w.id                              as warehouse_id
                        , date_trunc('month', p.in_date)    as in_month
                        , count(p.id)                       as cnt 
                     from pallets p
                     join reservations r
                       on r.id = p.reservation_id
                     join warehouses w
                       on w.id = r.warehouse_id
                    where p.in_date is not null
                    group by w.id
                           , date_trunc('month', p.in_date)
                 ) i
            full
            join ( select w.id                              as warehouse_id
                        , date_trunc('month', p.out_date)   as out_month
                        , count(p.id)                       as cnt
                     from pallets p
                     join reservations r
                       on r.id = p.reservation_id
                     join warehouses w
                       on w.id = r.warehouse_id
                    where p.in_date is not null
                      and p.out_date is not null
                    group
                       by w.id
                        , date_trunc('month', p.out_date)
                 ) o
              on o.warehouse_id is not distinct from i.warehouse_id
             and o.out_month = i.in_month
           order by coalesce(i.warehouse_id,o.warehouse_id)
                  , coalesce(i.in_month,o.out_month)
```

My personal preference is to use upper case for the functions, keywords and reserved words.

```
          SELECT COALESCE(i.warehouse_id,o.warehouse_id)                AS warehouse_id
               , COALESCE(i.in_month,o.out_month)                        AS month_
               , TO_CHAR(COALESCE(I.IN_MONTH,O.OUT_MONTH), 'FMMonth-YY') AS month_yy
               , COALESCE(i.cnt,0)                                       AS in_count
               , COALESCE(o.cnt,0)                                       AS out_count
            FROM ( SELECT w.id                              AS warehouse_id
                        , DATE_TRUNC('month', p.in_date)    AS in_month
                        , COUNT(p.id)                       AS cnt 
                     FROM pallets p
                     JOIN reservations r
                       ON r.id = p.reservation_id
                     JOIN warehouses w
                       ON w.id = r.warehouse_id
                    WHERE p.in_date IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY w.id
                           , DATE_TRUNC('month', p.in_date)
                 ) i
            FULL
            JOIN ( SELECT w.id                              AS warehouse_id
                        , DATE_TRUNC('month', p.out_date)   AS out_month
                        , COUNT(p.id)                       AS cnt
                     FROM pallets p
                     JOIN reservations r
                       ON r.id = p.reservation_id
                     JOIN warehouses w
                       ON w.id = r.warehouse_id
                    WHERE p.in_date IS NOT NULL
                      AND p.out_date IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY w.id
                           , DATE_TRUNC('month', p.out_date)
                 ) o
              ON o.warehouse_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM i.warehouse_id
             AND o.out_month = i.in_month
           ORDER BY COALESCE(i.warehouse_id,o.warehouse_id)
                  , COALESCE(i.in_month,o.out_month)
```

Comment: Did you really need to re-script entire query? Just use second one and comment on table aliases/keywords.

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was trying to create. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
    inbound AS (
        SELECT 
            warehouses.id,
            count(pallets.id),
            to_char(pallets.in_date, 'FMMonth-YY') AS in_month
        FROM
            pallets
            INNER JOIN
            reservations
                ON pallets.reservation_id = reservations.id
            INNER JOIN
            warehouses
                ON reservations.warehouse_id = warehouses.id
        WHERE pallets.in_date is not null
        GROUP BY
            warehouses.id,
            date_part('month', pallets.in_date),
            date_part('year', pallets.in_date),
            to_char(pallets.in_date, 'FMMonth-YY')),
    outbound AS (
        SELECT
            warehouses.id as id,
            count(pallets.id),
            to_char(pallets.out_date, 'FMMonth-YY') AS out_month
        FROM
            pallets
            INNER JOIN
            reservations
                ON pallets.reservation_id = reservations.id
            INNER JOIN
            warehouses
                ON reservations.warehouse_id = warehouses.id
        WHERE pallets.in_date is not null and pallets.out_date is not null
        GROUP BY
            date_part('month', pallets.out_date),
            date_part('year', pallets.out_date),
            to_char(pallets.out_date, 'FMMonth-YY'),
            warehouses.id)
SELECT
    coalesce(a.id, b.id) AS warehouse_id,
    coalesce(a.in_month, b.out_month) AS which_month,
    coalesce(a.count, 0) AS inbound,
    coalesce(b.count, 0) AS outbound
FROM
    inbound AS a
    FULL JOIN
    outbound AS b ON a.id = b.id AND a.in_month = b.out_month;
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the query I think you can trick the COUNT this way :

*Note: The query inside the WITH clause is maybe sufficient for you. However I added the WITH clause to be able to make a union. It depends on what you want the output to be.*

```
WITH computed_warehouses AS (
  -- Maybe this single select (inside the WITH is what you want)
  select 
    warehouses.id,
    count(pallets.id) as nb_in_date,
    count(pallets.id||pallets.out_date) as nb_out_date,
    -- Edit: count(pallets.out_date) as nb_out_date should also work and it's simpler
    to_char(pallets.in_date,  'FMMonth-YY') as in_month,
    to_char(pallets.out_date, 'FMMonth-YY') as out_month

 from pallets

 inner join reservations
         on pallets.reservation_id = reservations.id

 inner join warehouses
         on reservations.warehouse_id = warehouses.id

 where pallets.in_date is not null

 group by 
       warehouses.id,
       date_part('month', pallets.in_date),
       date_part('year', pallets.in_date),
       to_char(pallets.in_date, 'FMMonth-YY'),
       to_char(pallets.out_date, 'FMMonth-YY')

 order by 
       date_part('year', pallets.in_date),
       date_part('month', pallets.in_date)
)

-- If you wanna make a union
(
  SELECT
    t.id AS warehouse_id,
    t.in_month AS which_month,
    t.nb_in_date AS inbound,
    NULL AS outbound

   FROM computed_warehouses t
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT
    t.id AS warehouse_id,
    t.out_month AS which_month,
    NULL AS inbound,
    t.nb_out_date AS outbound

   FROM computed_warehouses t

  WHERE t.nb_out_date IS NOT NULL
    AND t.nb_out_date > 0
)
```

count(pallets.id||pallets.out_date) is a little tricky, it will count only pallets where out_date is not null. It can work well because *id* and *out_date* belongs to the same table and because count will not increment when null values.

**Edit** :
  `count(pallets.out_date) as nb_out_date` should work too, is simpler and should be faster